# Convert a relation into BCNF

Tags: rdbms, database-normalization

R (A B C)

AB -> C,
C -> A

AB is the minimal super key which is a candidate key.
AB -> C is good.

But C -> A doesn't hold good since prime attribute depends on Non Prime attribute. I know how to decompose till 3 NF. I also know why relation is not in BCNF.

But I don't know how to break this relation into BCNF. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi. Please edit your question to give what reference you are using and what *definition of BCNF* it gives and what *algorithm to decompose to BCNF* it gives. Notice that those require knowing *all* the CKs. So show what all the CKs are. Then follow the algorithm until you are stuck, then ask a question. You are just asking us to rewrite your textbook. PKs are irrelevant. Why are you mentioning them? Also "hold good" means nothing. Use the technical terms you were taught. PS Examples of definitions & decompositions are not presentations of algorithms; presentations of algorithms are.

Answer (score 1):

This relation can be decomposed in BCNF using for instance the analysis algorithm, which produces the following decomposition:

```
R1(A, C) (with non trivial dependency C → A and candidate key C)
R2(B, C) (without non trivial dependencies and so with candidate key (B, C))
```

But this decomposition does not preserve the dependencies: in fact, the dependency `A B → C` is lost. So, with such decomposition, the constraint due to this dependency cannot be simply enforced on the decomposed relations. And no other decomposition in BCNF can be produced such that the dependencies are maintained. We can note also that the relation is already in 3NF.